# How to find out what code tries to change url?

Tags: javascript, url, browser, listener

I have a javascript project (it is in angular-js, but it doesn't matter).
The url for a user page is localhost/myapp?user_id=47.
There is a list of products. I can navigate these products with arrows. The url changes without reloading the page:

- localhost/myapp?user_id=47#product_id=7
- localhost/myapp?user_id=47#product_id=11
- ...

I can find a keystroke event and locate the code which changes the parameter `product_id`.
But then, some unknown code changes it to some other url.

Is it possible to watch for changes in url? (i.e. some browser extension)
For example I would like to see backtrace for every moment when some code tries to change url.

Note that javascript watching for url changes is not a solution, because I am unable to find out what code tried to change the url.

Comment: like popstate? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WindowEventHandlers.onpopstate

Comment: Interesting idea, but it seems that navigation on products does not fire `popstate` event, while clicking back button does.